# passing url parameters to hidden field with javascript

Tags: javascript, url, parameters, field, hidden

I need help with below code.

What I need to do is to pass the URL parameters to these two hidden fields.
 http://www.yoursite.com/index.php?fieldOne=Work&fieldTwo=Play

It doesn't seem to be working. Also I cannot add id to the form field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="fieldOne">
    <input type="hidden" name="fieldTwo">
    <script>
    function FillForm() {
        var FormName = "myformname";
        var qLoc = location.href.indexOf('?');
    if(qLoc < 0) { return; }
    var q = location.href.substr(qLoc + 1);
    var list = q.split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        var kv = list[i].split('=');
        if(! eval('document.'+FormName+'.'+kv[0])) { continue; }
        kv[1] = unescape(kv[1]);
        if(kv[1].indexOf('"') > -1) {
            var re = /"/g;
            kv[1] = kv[1].replace(re,'\\"');
        }
      eval('document.'+FormName+'.'+kv[0]+'.value="'+kv[1]+'"');
      }
     }
    FillForm();
    </script>`
```

Comment: Instead of using eval you can use `[` and `]`: `document[FormName][kv[0]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NULL had it kind of there with the simplification (albiet there is a small error in your code regarding the iteration over the query). Here is NULL's simplification corrected, and also my guess as to why you're not getting the desired results:

```
<form name="myformname">
<input type="hidden" name="fieldOne">
<input type="hidden" name="fieldTwo">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var formName = "myformname",
  query = location.href.split("?").pop().split("&"),
  i = 0,
  len = query.length,
  split, elem;

  for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
      split = query[i].split("=");

      //alert(split);

      elem = document[formName][split[0]];

      if ( elem ) {
          elem.value = split[1].replace(/"/g, '\\"');
      }
  }
</script>
```

1) Make sure you're using a `form` tag with an id. I can't see your HTML.

2) Be sure that you are not seeing new data appear in the hidden `<input>`'s? I advise using a debugger and checking the live DOM tree as opposed to the source code. Some debuggers don't update the source in real-time.

EDIT:

Based on new information from the questioning party, here is another stab at a fix:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    var formName = "dSOfferAllE10Test-1349977611926";

    var query = location.href.split("?").pop().split("&");
    var len = query.length;
    var split, elem;

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {

        split = query[i].split("=");

        $('form[name="'+formName+'"]').find('input[name="'+split[0]+'"]').each(function(){

          $(this).val(split[1].replace(/"/g, '\\"'));

        });
    }
});

</script>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

This uses jQuery, so make sure that you attach a reference to jQuery in your `<head>` (or at least near the top of the `<body>` if you don't have access to the `<head>`. Best to grab the snippet from the Google-hosted version: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

Comment: I input your code and my page pops up a window shows the parameters fiedlOne, fieldTwo.  also my form code does have ids. also it is not working for me.

Comment: Ignore the alert, that is just for testing purposes. Please tell me what errors are thrown (if any) in your debugger. Also, let me know how much you know about debugging in a browser - because it sounds like you may not be doing any debugging at all...in which case, you need to look into how to debug with Chrome Developer tools or Firebug first...

Comment: you are right. I don't really how to debug. here is the landing page I am working on: view-source:http://www.datasitedeal.com/E10test?LeadSource=E10source&CampaignID=E10ID   what I tried to do is pass the leadsource and campaignid values into the hidden fields.

Comment: Okay, the issue is basically that the hidden input you're trying to reference is nested too deeply within various divs in order for the above code to work. The above code assumes that the <input> tag you're using is a child of the form. In your case, it isn't, it is a couple of children down. This is where something like jQuery would be useful. Will amend my answer above to reflect this conclusion.

Comment: cool Thanks. I can't really change the form codes. I am trying to get it work by using the javascript.

Comment: I've added an amendment to my answer. Remember that the values of the hidden HTML element will be changed - so you won't be able to double-check whether they have changed without some sort of debugger. But this should hopefully work.

Answer (score 0):

**You can simplify your code:**

```
var formName = "myformname",
    query = location.href.split("?").pop().split("&"),
    i = 0,
    len = query.length,
    split, elem;

for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
    split = query.split("=");
    elem = document[formName][split[0]];

    if ( elem ) {
        elem.value = split[1].replace(/"/g, '\\"');
    }
}
```

Comment: it is still not working. I am trying post the codes from my page but it  is giving me issues.